# PyGTK "assertion GTK_IS_WINDOW failed

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to build a web browser using PyGTK and PyWebKit

However, I'm pretty sure my question only concerns PyGTK

I have a custom gtk.Notebook class, with an "add tab" button as the last tab.
When I click it, it gives me the error

```
/home/ruiqimao/workspace/PyBrowser/src/browser/__init__.py:161: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_get_cursor: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed  gtk.main()
```

twice.

And then, my new tab won't show up.

I have no idea what is going on, so [here is my whole code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1001115/code.py)

If any of you could help me, that would be great!

Thanks!

[EDIT]: Just found out that the problem lies in the w.show_all() line
What could this mean?

Comment: If this is your code it should be obvious to you too the problem is not in `w.show_all()`. Check the `newTab` callback instead.

Comment: oh thanks! I forgot to show the new tab! xD
Thanks!

Comment: If you solved it, please post your solution as an answer and accept it. Otherwise, a little more code would be helpful for solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been sitting in "unanswered" for months, without any answer. However, the problem was indeed solved (see comments). Thus, as a service to get this question OUT of "unanswered", I'll restate the apparent answer. If anyone else can top me, pleeeeeeeease do. :)

**You forgot to show the new tab.**

Thank you, and goodnight. :)

Comment: xD I'll give it to you just because you somehow found this question... from... half a year ago... o.o

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I like monitoring the PyGTK tab, and this has been on the first page for months.